# Angular async http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to do a http ququest in angular. Somehow it seems am missing out on something which i cannot figure out what it is? 
On Page load i get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:undef] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/undef?p0=%24formServices
```

My Service:

```
app.factory('$formServices',['$http','$q',function ($http, $q) {

                function postSubmit (fData) {
                    return $http({
                        url: 'forms/Form1.php',
                        method: "POST",
                        data: { items: JSON.stringify(fData) }
                    });
                }
        }
    ]
);
```

And the controller that calls the service:

```
$formServices.postSubmit($scope.Parameters).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.Results = response;
                });
```

What am i missing out on?

Comment: Oops, scratch that last comment you need to return a function with your factory.

Comment: Factory must RETURN something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$injector:undef](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/undef)

Try adding a return to your factory. Also, if you wish to call the function with dot notation you need to place the function inside of an object.

```
app.factory('$formServices',['$http','$q',function ($http, $q) {

                return {
                    postSubmit: function(fData) {
                        return $http({
                            url: 'forms/Form1.php',
                            method: "POST",
                            data: { items: JSON.stringify(fData) }
                        });
                    }
                }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: When adding the return i get: TypeError: $formServices.postSubmit is not a function

Comment: Well your code only shows the function postSubmit. And it would need to be structured differently if that is how you wish to call it. The code shown would simply be called via `$formServices()`. Please update your question with all of your code if you need more help.

Comment: I think I understand what you want, hold on I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Factory must return object from `factory`, so that will be exposed via to factory consumer via injecting its dependency.

**Code**

```
app.factory('$formServices', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    function postSubmit(fData) {
        return $http({
            url: 'forms/Form1.php',
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                items: JSON.stringify(fData)
            }
        });
    }
    // should object
    return {
        postSubmit: postSubmit //link post submit to function
    }
}]);
```

Comment: @Xgongiveittoya this is refactoring of your code..which looks better to read and understand :)

Comment: Ah I see, its just taking the collection of objects and functions and returning them all together, instead of adding them to an object one at a time then returning the object.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your factory does not return an object. To learn more about this I suggest reading https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Evilzebra's answer would work I believe, but if you ever wanted to have more functionality in your factory, a good way to structure factories is:

```
app.factory('$formServices',['$http','$q',function ($http, $q) {
            var service = {};
            service.postSubmit = function (fData) {
                return $http({
                    url: 'forms/Form1.php',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { items: JSON.stringify(fData) }
                });
            }
            return service;
    }]);
```

This would allow you to add more features, appending them to the service object.